# Управление предложное, беспредложное

Tags: управление

Встречала два варианта: "вода с температурой 60 градусов Цельсия", "вода температурой 60 градусов Цельсия". Какой вариант является нормативным и почему?

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: вода температурой в 60 градусов  Цельсия, сравнить: дорога длиной в один километр.

Температура - внутренний признак воды, а предлог С используется для обозначения  внешнего или сопровождающего признака, например: платок с кружевами, нос с горбинкой.

Comment: А какие у воды "внешние признаки"? Или сопровождающие?

Comment: Нет таких признаков, поэтому некорректно сочетание "вода с температурой".

Comment: Почему же нет? Важной характеристикой воды является уровень ее рН. Вода с высоким уровнем ph.

Comment: Всё относительно и условно и зависит от ситуации. Вот мы говорим: это был человек высокого роста, с коротко стриженными волосами. Но можем сказать: люди с очень высоким ростом испытывают дискомфорт в общении.

Comment: Это полезная информация, но в случае с уровнем pH в воде возможен только один вариант: вода с высоким уровнем pH. Из чего я сдeлал вывод, что уровень pH - сопровождающий признак.

Comment: Если форма одна, то и выбирать нечего, а функции совмещены: и ваш pH основной и сопровождающий в одном  лице (или в чём там).